# Floating point data format sign+exponent

Tags: math

I am receiving data over UART from a heat meter, but I need some help to understand how i should deal with the data.
I have the documentation but that is not enough for me, I have to little experience with this kind of calculations.

Maybe someone with the right skill could explain to me how it should be done with a better example that I have from the documentation.

```
One value consists of the following bytes: 

[number of bytes][sign+exponent] (integer) 

(integer) is the register data value. The length of the integer value is 
specified by [number of bytes].   [sign+exponent] is an 8-bit value that 
specifies the sign of the data value and sign and value of the exponent. The 
meaning of the individual bits in the [sign+exponent] byte is shown below:
```

[image: Sign Exponent]

```
Examples: 

-123.45 = 04h, C2h, 0h, 0h, 30h, 39h 

87654321*103  = 04h, 03h , 05h, 39h, 7Fh, B1h 

255*103  = 01h, 03h , FFh
```

And now to one more example with actual data.

[image]

This is the information that I have from the documentation about this.

This is some data that I have received from my heat meter

`10 00 56 25 04 42 00 00 1B E4`

So in my example then 04 is the [number of bytes], 42 is the [sign+exponent] and 00 00 1B E4 is the (integer).
But I do not know how I should make the calculation to receive the actual value.

Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your data appears to be big-endian, according to your example. So here's how you break those bytes into the fields you need using bit shifting and masking.

```
n = b[0]
SI = (b[1] & 0x80) >> 7
SE = (b[1] & 0x40) >> 6
exponent = b[1] & 0x3f
integer = 0
for i = 0 to n-1:
    integer = (integer << 8) + b[2+i]
```

Comment: I am using this code in an Arduino sketch, with some modification so that it compiles but that should not change the result.
But i have one question, when I calculate SE from my example 0x42 then i get SE = 1 but in the reply from Yves Daoust then he gets the number -1.
What do you think about that?

And could you explain the part that calculates the integer, when I run the code then the result is -467992576 from the bytes 0x00 0x00 0x1B 0xE4 instead of 7140 (from the other reply).

Comment: @KristofferIsaksson since you didn't say which language you needed, I had no way to differentiate between signed and unsigned numbers. The calculation for `integer` should be performed as unsigned.

Comment: Yes, you are right, you did not have enough information from me to answer. I declare integer as unsigned int is there something more to it? And what do you think about the SE?

Comment: @KristofferIsaksson the bytes you work with should be unsigned too. As for SE, the formula you give where you take `-1^SE` assumes that `SE` will be 0 or 1: `-1^0 == 1`, `-1^1 == -1`.

Comment: Ahh now i understand SE.
a declared byte in arduino is always unsigned but i still does not receive the result of 7140 from the bytes 0x00 0x00 0x1B 0xE4, do you know that the code you replied with is working? and that the result should be 7140?

Comment: @KristofferIsaksson my mistake, the `for` loop was set up for little-endian and not big-endian. I've fixed it. See http://ideone.com/YQjeY4.

Answer (score 0):

The sign of the mantissa is obtained from the MSb of the Sign+exponent byte, by masking (`byte & 80h != 0 => SI = -1`).

The sign of the exponent is similarly obtained by `byte & 40h != 0 => SE = -1`.

The exponent value is `EXP = byte & 3Fh`.

The mantissa `INT` is the binary number formed by the four other bytes, which can be read as a single integer (but mind the indianness).

Finally, compute `SI * INT * pow(10, SE * EXP)`.

In your example, `SI = 1`, `SE = -1`, `EXP = 2`, `INT = 7140`, hence

```
1 * 7140 * pow(10, -1 * 2) = +71.4
```

---

It is not in the scope of this answer to explain how to implement this efficiently.

Comment: I have to read this post a couple of more time before i get it all but could you explain to me once more how you get the integer 7140 from the four bytes 00 00 1B E4

Comment: @KristofferIsaksson: you read an `int` variable from the address, using a pointer.

Comment: I really appreciate you trying to explain this to me, I am sorry but I still does not get it. I understand if you soon give up on me.